# ffmpeg: 1 frame manipulation on demand

Tags: php, c++, c, ffmpeg

**Hello folks & friends of SO!**

We need to create a small application to take a random frame from a video, and apply some modifications to it, in real time.

**This has to be done in real time,** and in order to do that, we wouldn't mind to create some initial delay, before the video starts streaming. So let's assume **we have a total of 6 seconds of preloading time,** in order to:

```
1) extract a keyframe.
2) create an image with it.
3) manipulate the image.
4) replace the original keyframe with the new one.
```

The point (3) of the previous algorithm is already solved using GD as a PHP module. However we would need to find a solution for the rest of the procedure in order to accomplish this.

Please if anyone is available to help us with this, feel free to contact me.

**Thanks in advance;
Chris C. Russo**

Comment: Replacing a keyframe correctly requires replacing every frame that depends on that keyframe, either directly or indirectly. With that said, you may be able to get by with replacing just the frames that depend directly on the keyframe, as long as they are encoded at sufficiently high quality.

Comment: That sounds great, is there may be any fragment of code, or POC for this that you could provide? I'd like to see more. Thanks!

Comment: This is a big enough problem that I really wouldn't know where to begin, and I don't think there's any sample code or tutorial for doing something like this. In my opinion, the ideal solution would be a higher-level library that lets you do minimalistic in-place modification of compressed video using the ffmpeg libraries, but that would be a huge project in itself. Unless you're already an expert at this (in which case you wouldn't need to ask), you probably need to hire somebody who's an ffmpeg expert and looking for this kind of work...

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complicated problem that cannot be solved by simply replacing the keyframe with a modified image. Following problems (at least) should be addressed for this to work:

- Re-encoding all the frames that depend on the keyframe. Otherwise, the video would be corrupt.
- File format considerations - The modified keyframe and subsequent frames are likely to have a different size after encoding (compared to the original encoded data). Storing them in the output file is not easy
- Timestamp - The timestamp information for these modified frames must be preserved, else there would be audio-video sync issues in the output file.

Given these issues, my recommendation is to perform the image manipulation in the raw video frame, and encode the stream afterwards. Please let me know if I can help clarify.

Comment: Mr krthkr, your response was actually very clear. If I may ask, would you be interested in providing a solution for us? We don't have a huge budget, but we can still sort it out! Please let me know, you can email me at chris (at)          calciumsec         (dot)     com, all together.

Comment: Hello Chris, I am definitely intrigued, and would like to know more about the problem you are trying to solve. Thanks for sharing your email, and I will contact you today.